# Why my canvas filter is not working even after rendering as canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, frontend

I am trying to develop a image filter using canvas.My image is converting to canvas as soon as it is loaded but the filter effect is not affecting the image at all,i.e., image is unchanged in canvas.

```
<img id="image" src="file:///C:/Users/G%20COMTECH%20SYSTEM/Favorites/Pictures/2015-01/2.%20Knitting%20Balls.jpg" />




<script type="text/javascript">





var image = document.getElementById('image');
 
if(image.complete){ // From cache
desaturateImage(image);
} else { // On load
  image.addEventListener('load', function() {
     desaturateImage(image);
  });
}

function desaturateImage(image){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    image.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas, image);
canvas.width  = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
image.parentNode.removeChild(image);

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var data = imgData.data;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        var grey = (0.2126 * data[i]) + (0.7152 * data[i + 1]) + (0.0722 * data[i + 2]);
    data[i] = grey;
    data[i + 1] = grey;
    data[i + 2] = grey;
}
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0,0);
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
```

Now i updated my javascript,it is working if the image is taken from other sites but if i am taking image from same page,it's not applying filter again.

```js
var sample=document.getElementById('image');
var url=sample.src;
var image = new Image();
document.write(sample.src);
image.src = url + '?' + new Date().getTime();
//image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
document.write(image.src);

image.onload = function(){
  desaturateImage(this);
}

function desaturateImage(image) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
  canvas.width = 400;
  canvas.height = 400;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0,0);
  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var data = imgData.data;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    var grey = (0.2126 * data[i]) + (0.7152 * data[i + 1]) + (0.0722 * data[i + 2]);
    data[i] = grey;
    data[i + 1] = grey;
    data[i + 2] = grey;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
  //ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465101162946-4377e57745c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"/>
<canvas id="mycanvas" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Because you're overwriting the modified image with the source image in the last line: `ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** Modified to read an uploaded image.

Modified your code a little, the `ctx.drawImage` at the end is causing the issue.

```js
/*var url = 'http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465101162946-4377e57745c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80';
var image = new Image();
image.src = url + '?' + new Date().getTime();
image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
image.onload = function(){
  desaturateImage(this);
}*/

function openFile(file){
  var input = file.target;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(){
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = reader.result;
    image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
    image.onload = function(){
      desaturateImage(image);
    }
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}

function desaturateImage(image) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var data = imgData.data;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    var grey = (0.2126 * data[i]) + (0.7152 * data[i + 1]) + (0.0722 * data[i + 2]);
    data[i] = grey;
    data[i + 1] = grey;
    data[i + 2] = grey;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
  //ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='openFile(event)'><br/>
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I am trying to apply filter to my image from local machine.I put some changes in your code like

Comment: `var sample=document.getElementById('image');
var url=sample.src;`

Comment: It is now showing local image but did not use filter again

Comment: Can you add a working code snippet to your answer to demonstrate the problem? Use any image - local or remote doesn't matter.

Comment: I cannot run the snippet, maybe remove the `<script>` tags in the JS part.

Comment: Even if i will remove the tag,it will not gonna be work as image will not be loaded from my workstation to this site

Comment: Why are you not using a remote image, for the sake of this example?

Comment: What i am trying to achieve that user uploads their picture and it get edited without loading or visiting any other page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189306/discussion-between-anurag-srivastava-and-gagan).